# Adding a Unix timestamp to logs

Tags: bash, unix

I'm using the following command to write the output of a cron job to a file.

```
python manage.py do_something >> /var/log/do_something_log.txt 2>&1
```

I want to have the Unix timestamp prepended to the name of the file, something like,

```
python manage.py do_something >> /var/log/{{timestamp}}_do_something_log.txt 2>&1
```

I tried,

```
python manage.py do_something >> /var/log/'date + %s'_do_something_log.txt 2>&1
```

but this doesn't work.

What can I try next?

Comment: Replace `'date +%s'` with `"$(date +%s)"` and should work fine. This works fine in my bash: `echo hi >./test"$(date +%s)".txt; ls *.txt`

Comment: `'date ...'` is not the same as `\`date ...\``.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou that worked for me, You might want to put that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

### This Will Work:

```
 python manage.py do_something >> /var/log/$(date +%Y)_do_something_log.txt 2>&1
```

> Output: /var/log/2018_do_something_log.txt

#### With %s instead:

```
python manage.py do_something >> /var/log/$(date +%s)_do_something_log.txt 2>&1
```

> Output: /var/log/1544438322_do_something_log.txt

Comment: you should quote the filename.